Check whether user input is correct with a mask / Groovy
I want to create a verification for a user-input field, which will help to identify whether a user had filled it in correctly or not. The verification is a mask-based - [0-9]{10}, therefore if a user enters "123", the system should notify them about the incorrest input, and if the user enters "1234567891" then everything should be fine. I cannot understand which function should I use, so that the verification works out.
def test := "[0-9]{10}"
if(user_value = test){
return true
}
else{
false
}


One way to accomplish this:
def pattern = ~/[0-9]{10}/
def prompt = "Enter a 10-digit number: "

def result
while (true) {
    result = System.console().readLine(prompt)
    if (result?.matches(pattern)) break;
    
    println "Invalid input. Please try again."
}

println "You entered: $result"

executing this gives:
➤ groovy solution.groovy
Enter a 10-digit number: adfs
Invalid input. Please try again.
Enter a 10-digit number: 123456
Invalid input. Please try again.
Enter a 10-digit number: 1234567890
You entered: 1234567890

tested on:
Groovy Version: 4.0.22 JVM: 21.0.2 Vendor: Oracle Corporation OS: Mac OS X


Thanks! Do you know why there might be a problem like this? "no viable alternative at input '/' "

The "no viable alternative at input '/'" message is Antlr's fallback syntax error message if we have no special error message configured in the parser. It possibly means you are trying to use one of Groovy's syntax shorthands in a place not allowed.
